# Pulseaudio HDMI sinks change names

Tags: pulseaudio

I'm fiddling with a minor inconvenience regarding `pulseaudio` that I can't figure out.
I have a ThinkPadT460s running Arch Linux, together with a docking station. Connected to that dock are a screen and my TV via a receiver.

The output of `xrandr` is

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 5760 x 2160, maximum 32767 x 32767
eDP1 connected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
   2560x1440     60.00 +  48.00    59.95  
   1920x1440     60.00  
   1856x1392     60.01  
   1792x1344     60.01  
   2048x1152     60.00    59.90    59.91  
   1920x1200     59.88    59.95  
   1920x1080     59.96    60.00    59.93  
   1600x1200     60.00  
   1680x1050     59.95    59.88  
   1400x1050     59.98  
   1600x900      60.00    59.95    59.82  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1400x900      59.96    59.88  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1368x768      60.00    59.88    59.85  
   1280x800      59.81    59.91  
   1280x720      59.86    60.00    59.74  
   1024x768      60.00  
   1024x576      60.00    59.90    59.82  
   960x540       60.00    59.63    59.82  
   800x600       60.32    56.25  
   864x486       60.00    59.92    59.57  
   640x480       59.94  
   720x405       59.51    60.00    58.99  
   640x360       59.84    59.32    60.00  
DP1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP2-1 connected 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 1220mm x 680mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+  50.00    59.94    30.00    24.00    29.97    23.98  
   4096x2160     24.00    23.98  
   3840x2160     30.00    25.00    24.00    29.97    23.98  
   1680x1050     59.88  
   1600x900      60.00  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1280x720      60.00    50.00    30.00    59.94    29.97    24.00    23.98  
   1024x768      60.00  
   800x600       60.32  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       60.00    59.94  
   640x480       60.00    59.94  
DP2-2 connected primary 3840x2160+1920+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 620mm x 340mm
   3840x2160     60.00*+  30.00    25.00    24.00    29.97    23.98  
   1920x2160     59.99  
   2560x1440     59.95  
   1920x1080     60.00    60.00    50.00    50.00    59.94  
   1680x1050     59.95  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1280x720      60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1024x768      60.00  
   800x600       60.32    56.25  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       60.00    59.94  
   640x480       60.00    59.94  
DP2-3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
VIRTUAL1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

Now if I connect the TV, I also want to switch sound to HDMI. In a script that switches between my screen configuration I also added a line to change the sound, f.e. to switch back to internal sound I have 
`pactl set-card-profile 0 output:analog-stereo`.

However, the TV (DP2-1 here) seemingly switches IDs in pulseaudio. Sometimes I need to use `pactl set-card-profile 0 output:hdmi-stereo-extra1` (which is called HDMI 2 internally) and sometimes `pactl set-card-profile 0 output:hdmi-stereo-extra3` (which is called HDMI 4 internally) and I haven't really figured out why. I also can't really see any specific trigger for this, sometimes after reboot the profile name switches.

Does anyone have an idea what to test to figure out what is going on here?

Comment: Does it only switch after reboot, or also on other occasions? If it switches only after reboot, the "trigger" is that the enumeration of hardware is not deterministic (like in many other cases).

Comment: Yeah I figured something like that. I also had the problem with the screen detection initially. `xrandr` somewhat gets that right again and I was curious how that actually happens. Yes, that's mainly after boot but I didn't want to close out that it can also happen during runtime so far.

Answer (score 2):

I can give an unsatisfactory but working answer after trying a few things.

Consulting the output of `pactl list cards` a little closer when my TV is switched on the entry showed an actual device name:

```
[...]
                hdmi-output-3: HDMI / DisplayPort 4 (priority: 5600, latency offset: 0 usec, available)
                        Eigenschaften:
                                device.icon_name = "video-display"
                                device.product.name = "VSX-330"
                        Teil der/des Profil(s): output:hdmi-stereo-extra3, output:hdmi-stereo-extra3+input:analog-stereo, output:hdmi-surround-extra3, output:hdmi-surround-extra3+input:analog-stereo, output:hdmi-surround71-extra3, output:hdmi-surround71-extra3+input:analog-stereo
[...]
```

Since I'm looking for the simple stereo-profile, I can get this specific entry with

```
pactl set-card-profile 0 $(pactl list cards | grep -A1 'VSX-330' | awk '{print substr($4, 1, length($4)-1)}' | tail -1)
```

This is not pretty but seems to have done the trick so far. It seems to be related with my screen not being particularly quick in registering with pulseaudio when I dock my device.

Hopefully that fixes the issue and helps others with similar problems!